# Unclear Part of Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to 'read' a script (viz. [this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/brlcad/code/HEAD/tree/brlcad/trunk/src/archer/archer), but that's not important) but I'm stuck at one part. I can't understand what the script is doing here, maybe because I don't know too much shell scripting, maybe because I'm used to bash scripts and not just #!/bin/sh.

Here's the part I'm having trouble understanding:

```
if {[info exists argv] && $argv != ""} {
    package require cadwidgets::GeometryIO
    set target [cadwidgets::geom_load [lindex $argv 0] 1]
    $::ArcherCore::application Load $target
}
```

What does it mean? Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that's not important

In fact, it's the most important missing part. The script runs in `wish`, not `sh`:

```
exec "$WISH" "$0" "$@"
```

Comment: It's actually a hybrid `sh`/`tcl` script. The `#\ ` lines are interpreted by Tcl as multi-line comments, but not `sh`, so the `sh` parts of the script are hidden from the Tcl interpreter once it runs.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought about it this way.